# User class for Spring Security application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, architecture

I am currently developing a multi user Spring Boot application with JPA/Hibernate and an Angular 2 frontend. I envision two basic types of users: Vendors and customers.

Before starting to code I crafted a UML class diagram with the class `User` and two subclasses `Customer` and `Vendor`. The reason for the subclasses is that they have different attributes: e.g. a vendor should be able to write a general description about himself whereas a customer should be able to save favorites.

The following picture is an excerpt of my class diagram:

[image: UML class diagram snippet]

As it's my first app with Login/Registration feature I started reading tutorials about how to implement a Login and Registration feature with Spring Security. Over time, I had to realize that basically all the samples contain only one `User` class, whose privileges are determined upon his `Role`s, which is typically a recommended/needed class to achieve the above mentioned functionality.

It appears to me that the `User` class is not meant to have subclasses, but naturally the tutorials and samples mostly cover the basic setup and not the representation of a complex business model with completely different users.

My question is the following: is it feasible and advisable to create subclasses of the `User` class which I want to use for the authorization with a custom `UserDetailsService` class? If not, do you recommend merging the attributes from the `Customer` and `Vendor` class into the `User` class and consequently determine upon the `User`'s roles if he should be able to have a certain attribute and otherwise it will just be null?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: U can use any class which extends UserDetails, there are no problems. Spring Security just grab the  UserDetails implementation returned from your UserDetailService, and will place it to security context. But i think it will be no so convenient if you will operate with few userdetails implementations=)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring security work with `UserDetailsService` interface for authentication and authorize features. You should implement `loadUserByUsername` function for load `User` from database or in memory or any where.

Spring security work with `UserDetails` interface as model. Therefore your `User` entity need to implement `UserDetails` interface that spring security can work with that.

Now, you have `User` entity that can inherited like other entities and you can annotate it with `@Inheritance` like below:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Length(min=5)
    private String password;
    private String username;

    @Email
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean verified;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Authority> roles= new HashSet<>();

    //...
}

@Entity
public class Vendor extends User{
        private String name;
        private String description;
        private Date openingTime;
        private Date closingTime;
        @ManyToOne
        private List<File> images;
        //...
}

@Entity
public class Customer extends User{
        private String forename;
        private String surname;
        @ManyToOne
        private List<PaymentDetails> paymentDetailsList;
        //...
}
```